# Android Exoplayer Selector / Highlighted Icon Color and Shape Change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, exoplayer, android-tv

I am trying to make an Android TV app with exoplayer. The current look of video ui is basic exoplayer PlayerView.
[Current Look of Exo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C6hF.png)

But when I run the app on TV, I am not be able to see where the selector/highlighted icon is?
How can I get a look similar (I just want to a square cursor/selector) like below?
[Desired Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofjrF.png)

I tried to implement it with external drawable and layout files but i could not manage it.